# Ridiculously slow MySQL Queries in Joomla 3.x

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, joomla, joomla3.1

Before I go any further, let me just say, I've already done everything that's recommended when you google "slow joomla" or "optimize joomla". That is, my site is GZipped, all of my css and js are optimized and minified, I'm not running any unnecessary components, plugins, or modules (hardly any, in fact), my images are optimized, caching is turned on (both page and Progressive) and I'm on supah-fast cloud hosting from Rackspace, with my SQL Database on a separate Rackspace server.

All of that, and I'm still getting load times upwards of 10-12 seconds, sometimes as much as 14-15.

From Joomla debug:

```
Application 0.000 seconds (+0.000); 0.75 MB (+0.755) - afterLoad
Application 0.027 seconds (+0.027); 2.25 MB (+1.491) - afterInitialise
Application 0.040 seconds (+0.013); 3.26 MB (+1.010) - afterRoute
Application 11.986 seconds (+11.947); 5.09 MB (+1.833) - afterDispatch
Application 12.000 seconds (+0.014); 5.63 MB (+0.539) - beforeRenderModule mod_chronoforms (Tip Line)
Application 12.006 seconds (+0.005); 5.85 MB (+0.225) - afterRenderModule mod_chronoforms (Tip Line)
Application 12.008 seconds (+0.002); 5.86 MB (+0.006) - beforeRenderModule mod_custom_advanced (Sponsors)
Application 12.009 seconds (+0.002); 5.88 MB (+0.019) - afterRenderModule mod_custom_advanced (Sponsors)
Application 12.010 seconds (+0.001); 5.87 MB (-0.006) - beforeRenderModule mod_flexi_customcode (Popular Now)
Application 12.012 seconds (+0.002); 5.89 MB (+0.018) - afterRenderModule mod_flexi_customcode (Popular Now)
Application 12.012 seconds (+0.001); 5.84 MB (-0.046) - beforeRenderModule mod_articles_category (Featured Articles)
Application 12.033 seconds (+0.021); 5.97 MB (+0.127) - afterRenderModule mod_articles_category (Featured Articles)
Application 12.033 seconds (+0.000); 5.96 MB (-0.014) - beforeRenderModule mod_search (Search)
Application 12.036 seconds (+0.002); 5.98 MB (+0.022) - afterRenderModule mod_search (Search)
Application 12.036 seconds (+0.001); 5.93 MB (-0.050) - beforeRenderModule mod_acymailing (AcyMailing Module)
Application 12.044 seconds (+0.007); 6.44 MB (+0.507) - afterRenderModule mod_acymailing (AcyMailing Module)
Application 12.157 seconds (+0.114); 6.72 MB (+0.289) - afterRender
```

the (+11.947) for afterDispatch is what tipped me off that it was probably an issue with the MySQL queries, so I started running some of the long (long, LONG) ones through PHPMyAdmin.

I found that queries such as these (the first of which loads 8 articles for the category-blog view -- as far as I understand, the second does the same search, minus the `LIMIT`, to allow for pagination) take over 2 or 3 second EACH to complete and there are 40-some-odd queries (though the vast majority are nowhere near as unwieldy) every time a page loads:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.introtext, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias, 
  CASE WHEN a.modified = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN a.created ELSE a.modified END as modified, a.modified_by, uam.name as modified_by_name,
  CASE WHEN a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN a.created ELSE a.publish_up END as publish_up,a.publish_down, a.images, a.urls, a.attribs, a.metadata, a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access, a.hits, a.xreference, a.featured, LENGTH(a.fulltext) AS readmore,
  CASE WHEN badcats.id is not null THEN 0 ELSE a.state END AS state,c.title AS category_title, c.path AS category_route, c.access AS category_access, c.alias AS category_alias,
  CASE WHEN a.created_by_alias > ' ' THEN a.created_by_alias ELSE ua.name END AS author,ua.email AS author_email,contact.id as contactid,parent.title as parent_title, parent.id as parent_id, parent.path as parent_route, parent.alias as parent_alias,ROUND(v.rating_sum / v.rating_count, 0) AS rating, v.rating_count as rating_count,c.published, 
  CASE WHEN badcats.id is null THEN c.published ELSE 0 END AS parents_published 
  FROM mydatabase_content AS a 
  LEFT JOIN mydatabase_content_frontpage AS fp 
  ON fp.content_id = a.id 
  LEFT JOIN mydatabase_categories AS c 
  ON c.id = a.catid 
  LEFT JOIN mydatabase_users AS ua 
  ON ua.id = a.created_by 
  LEFT JOIN mydatabase_users AS uam 
  ON uam.id = a.modified_by 
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT contact.user_id, MAX(contact.id) AS id, contact.language 
  FROM mydatabase_contact_details AS contact 
  WHERE contact.published = 1 
  GROUP BY contact.user_id, contact.language) AS contact 
  ON contact.user_id = a.created_by 
  LEFT JOIN mydatabase_categories as parent 
  ON parent.id = c.parent_id 
  LEFT JOIN mydatabase_content_rating AS v 
  ON a.id = v.content_id 
  LEFT 
  OUTER JOIN (SELECT cat.id as id 
  FROM mydatabase_categories AS cat JOIN mydatabase_categories AS parent 
  ON cat.lft BETWEEN parent.lft 
  AND parent.rgt 
  WHERE parent.extension = 'com_content' 
  AND parent.published != 1 
  GROUP BY cat.id ) AS badcats 
  ON badcats.id = c.id 
  WHERE a.access IN (1,1,5) 
  AND c.access IN (1,1,5) 
  AND 
  CASE WHEN badcats.id is null THEN a.state ELSE 0 END = 1 
  AND (a.catid = 164 OR a.catid IN ( SELECT sub.id 
  FROM mydatabase_categories as sub 
  INNER JOIN mydatabase_categories as this 
  ON sub.lft > this.lft 
  AND sub.rgt < this.rgt 
  WHERE this.id = 164)) 
  AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2013-08-07 07:00:01') 
  AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2013-08-07 07:00:01') 
  GROUP BY a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.introtext, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias, a.created, a.modified, a.modified_by, uam.name, a.publish_up, a.attribs, a.metadata, a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access, a.hits, a.xreference, a.featured, a.fulltext, a.state, a.publish_down, badcats.id, c.title, c.path, c.access, c.alias, uam.id, ua.name, ua.email, contact.id, parent.title, parent.id, parent.path, parent.alias, v.rating_sum, v.rating_count, c.published, c.lft, a.ordering, parent.lft, fp.ordering, c.id, a.images, a.urls 
  ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN a.created ELSE a.publish_up END DESC , a.created 
LIMIT 0, 7
```

---

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.introtext, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias, 
  CASE WHEN a.modified = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN a.created ELSE a.modified END as modified, a.modified_by, uam.name as modified_by_name,
  CASE WHEN a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN a.created ELSE a.publish_up END as publish_up,a.publish_down, a.images, a.urls, a.attribs, a.metadata, a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access, a.hits, a.xreference, a.featured, LENGTH(a.fulltext) AS readmore,
  CASE WHEN badcats.id is not null THEN 0 ELSE a.state END AS state,c.title AS category_title, c.path AS category_route, c.access AS category_access, c.alias AS category_alias,
  CASE WHEN a.created_by_alias > ' ' THEN a.created_by_alias ELSE ua.name END AS author,ua.email AS author_email,contact.id as contactid,parent.title as parent_title, parent.id as parent_id, parent.path as parent_route, parent.alias as parent_alias,ROUND(v.rating_sum / v.rating_count, 0) AS rating, v.rating_count as rating_count,c.published, 
  CASE WHEN badcats.id is null THEN c.published ELSE 0 END AS parents_published 
  FROM mydatabase_content AS a 
  LEFT JOIN mydatabase_content_frontpage AS fp 
  ON fp.content_id = a.id 
  LEFT JOIN mydatabase_categories AS c 
  ON c.id = a.catid 
  LEFT JOIN mydatabase_users AS ua 
  ON ua.id = a.created_by 
  LEFT JOIN mydatabase_users AS uam 
  ON uam.id = a.modified_by 
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT contact.user_id, MAX(contact.id) AS id, contact.language 
  FROM mydatabase_contact_details AS contact 
  WHERE contact.published = 1 
  GROUP BY contact.user_id, contact.language) AS contact 
  ON contact.user_id = a.created_by 
  LEFT JOIN mydatabase_categories as parent 
  ON parent.id = c.parent_id 
  LEFT JOIN mydatabase_content_rating AS v 
  ON a.id = v.content_id 
  LEFT 
  OUTER JOIN (SELECT cat.id as id 
  FROM mydatabase_categories AS cat JOIN mydatabase_categories AS parent 
  ON cat.lft BETWEEN parent.lft 
  AND parent.rgt 
  WHERE parent.extension = 'com_content' 
  AND parent.published != 1 
  GROUP BY cat.id ) AS badcats 
  ON badcats.id = c.id 
  WHERE a.access IN (1,1,5) 
  AND c.access IN (1,1,5) 
  AND 
  CASE WHEN badcats.id is null THEN a.state ELSE 0 END = 1 
  AND (a.catid = 164 OR a.catid IN ( SELECT sub.id 
  FROM mydatabase_categories as sub 
  INNER JOIN mydatabase_categories as this 
  ON sub.lft > this.lft 
  AND sub.rgt < this.rgt 
  WHERE this.id = 164)) 
  AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2013-08-07 07:00:01') 
  AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2013-08-07 07:00:01') 
  GROUP BY a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.introtext, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias, a.created, a.modified, a.modified_by, uam.name, a.publish_up, a.attribs, a.metadata, a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access, a.hits, a.xreference, a.featured, a.fulltext, a.state, a.publish_down, badcats.id, c.title, c.path, c.access, c.alias, uam.id, ua.name, ua.email, contact.id, parent.title, parent.id, parent.path, parent.alias, v.rating_sum, v.rating_count, c.published, c.lft, a.ordering, parent.lft, fp.ordering, c.id, a.images, a.urls 
  ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN a.created ELSE a.publish_up END DESC , a.created
```

### EDIT

Here's the `EXPLAIN` for the first query:

[image: EXPLAIN query 1]

And for the second:

[image: EXPAIN query 2]

My _content table is a little over 14,000 rows, which I know isn't really all that much in the grand scheme of things.

### /EDIT

Has anyone found a good way to optimize this? I'm not opposed to hacking the core (I know they say not to, but what's the point of an open source project if you can't get in and fiddle with it?) if that's what it takes.

### EDIT 2 - SOLVED (sort of).

So, I found [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065038/joomla-mysql-performance) who seems to be going down the right path, so I said to hell with it, and tried it.

In components/com_content/models/articles.php, I replaced `line 431`

```
$query->where('(a.publish_up = ' . $nullDate . ' OR a.publish_up <= ' . $nowDate . ')')
                ->where('(a.publish_down = ' . $nullDate . ' OR a.publish_down >= ' . $nowDate . ')');
```

with

```
$query->where('(a.publish_up >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))');
```

I know this won't work for everyone, as it probably breaks pagination, but it seems to be working for me so far (my template uses a js infinite scroll solution instead of pagination). I figure if anyone is looking for an article over a year old, they can use the Search function.

Those two queries now each take less that .04 seconds to complete, and the afterDispatch time from Joomla Debug is down to 1.469 seconds -- not optimal, but a number I can live with and continue to whittle down.

I know this solution is pretty hacky, and probably won't work for anyone else, so I'd love to hear more ideas about improving/optimizing the Joomla core and the Joomla stock queries.

Thanks SO!

### /EDIT 2

Comment: What was the duration of the query length when running through PHPMYADMIN?

Comment: The first query I listed above (the one with `LIMIT 0,7` set) took 2.9469 sec; the second took 4.4829 sec. I'm going to edit my question with `EXPLAIN`s for both.

Comment: where have You indexes ? How does schema looks like ?

Comment: I indexed `publish_up`, because all of my category-blogs are organized by publication date. I can hardly find any documentation on properly indexing tables for use with Joomla.

Comment: I know this is a little off-topic but to my experience there's no such thing as "supah-fast cloud hosting from Rackspace". I dealt with them twice on different occasions and the performance was horrible. I know I am not the only one with this type of problem, just Google for "rackspace slow" and you will see that according to quite a few people, it's a common issue with them.

Comment: I may have been overzealous in referring to it as being supah-fast -- after doing a traceroute to my server, I think you might be right. Moreso, I was just trying to illustrate that I wasn't on some GoDaddy shared hosting nonsense -- I was trying to avoid the typical answers to slow joomla questions (i.e. "don't use so many extensions", "get better hosting", "throw more hardware at it"). It infuriates me that these are the typical answers, since they all seem to be band-aids covering a massive, gaping chest wound of a problem. I hate treating symptoms, when we should be looking for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As I have posted here already: [JOOMLA site too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566732/joomla-site-too-slow)

I uncommented the

```
bind-address="127.0.0.1"
```

setting in the MySQL configuration file (my.ini).

This brought an increase of execution speed to my local Joomla installation on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the join on the contact table and the resulting group_by.
This is fixed in master with https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/1542 and I think it should already be included in the current release.
Which version of Joomla are you using?

Answer (score -1):

i had a problem on windwos hosting php+mysql. set host to ip address.

```
host 127.0.0.1
```