# JOOMLA site too slow

Tags: apache, joomla, xampp, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

my Joomla site is too slow. It approximately uses 8 to 10 s to load main page. I am using xampp. template protostar. PC core i7. OS windows. JOOMLA 3.15. Is it normal ??

OR any any one may please guide me how to debug this issue.

[image: Snap shot form chrome developer network tab]

Comment: i just installed joomla no new extension not even a single change Xampp 1.8.2 php 5.41.  i think 8 sec are not acceptable from local host.

Comment: hmm ok. yeah 8 seconds is rather a lot for a newly installed Joomla site. Try using [Wampserver](http://wampserver.com/en) to see if there is any difference in speed. This is not normal, but please bare @Brent Friar's answer in mind as it is useful information.

Comment: In index.php i added start timer and stop timer events at beginning and end of file. time was 1.8 sec  but website still loads in 8sec. i follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148131/xampp-wamp-whatever-it-is-apache-is-running-super-slow time reduces to 0.5 sec but website still load in browser in 8 sec. I think there is either preloading delay or post loading delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oppz i solved it just right now. I disable Xdebug in php.ini and time reduces form 8s to 1s

```
[XDebug]
;zend_extension= "C:\Users\arslan\Desktop\xampp-win32-1.8.1-VC9\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll" 
;xdebug.remote_enable=on
;xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
;xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
;xdebug.remote_port=9001
;xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

my server was xampp.

Joomla site slow problem solved.

Its running like leopard now.

OS window7

workstation corei7

localhost

Edit::
And time reduces to 0.5 sec when i removed following code form protostar index.php i.e google fonts

```
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo    
$this->params->get('googleFontName');?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
      <style type="text/css">
         h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.site-title{
            font-family: '<?php echo str_replace('+', ' ', $this->params->get('googleFontName'));?>', sans-serif;
         }
      </style>
```

Comment: do use a php accelerator for CMS like these, gurantee 50% reduce in memory and at least 20% from time
[APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) : my favourite :D

Answer (score 4):

LIn your configuration.php make sure you have `public $host = '127.0.0.1';`, instead of `'localhost'`. This is an php/mysql issue. For me it is 1 second differance for every db connection.

When you have joomla debug mode on, you get time information:

localhost: 
[image]

127.0.0.1:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the issue is when you are working on xampp/win because that set up is inherently slower than a *nix server that has been set up to run Joomla. As with most web software, Joomla is vastly affected by the hosting environment. Getting a good host is critical in site speed. We recently helped a client with site speed problems simply by moving them to a dedicated server optimized for Joomla. Load times went from 6-8 second to under 2 seconds and we didn't do anything but move the site.

I wouldn't worry about it until you get it on a production server. Even then, I would make sure you are on a quality host that specializes in Joomla like RochenHost.com.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above mentioned answer I uncommented the

```
bind-address="127.0.0.1"
```

setting in the MySQL configuration file (my.ini).

This brought an increase of execution speed to my local Joomla installation on Windows 8.1.